# How can I configure CCSID value in my Queue Manager using "pymqi" Python library?

Tags: python, ibm-mq, pymqi

I'm currently developing an application which needs to connect a MQ Queue in order to have the queue saving message information inside another service. Once it's done, the service returns a result message through the MQ Queue and it is returned to me.

I'm sending a string message that contains a XML message similar to the following one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<peticionDemanda>
<subtipo>DEMANDA CONTRATACIÓN</subtipo>
</peticionDemanda>
```

It appears that MQ is not decoding properly the "Ó" character and "subtipo" field is being saved as "DEMANDA CONTRATACI├ôN".

**I'm encoding the message in "UTF-8" and I've been told that the CCSID I'm using to send the message is 850 instead of 1208 (the one belonging to UTF-8).**

To run the MQ manager, I'm using **"pymqi" Python library in Client Mode**. This is the MQManager class I use to send messages to the queue and get the response:

```py
class MQManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue_manager = config.queue_manager
        self.channel = config.channel
        self.port = config.port
        self.host = config.host
        self.conn_info = config.conn_info
        self.queue_request_name = config.queue_request_name
        self.queue_response_name = config.queue_response_name

        cd = pymqi.CD()
        cd.ChannelName = self.channel
        cd.ConnectionName = self.conn_info
        cd.ChannelType = pymqi.CMQC.MQCHT_CLNTCONN
        cd.TransportType = pymqi.CMQC.MQXPT_TCP

        self.qmgr = pymqi.QueueManager(None)
        self.qmgr.connect_with_options(self.queue_manager, opts=pymqi.CMQC.MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_NO_BLOCK, cd=cd)

    def send_message(self, str_xml_message):
        # set message descriptor
        request_md = pymqi.MD()
        request_md.ReplyToQ = self.queue_response_name
        request_md.Format = pymqi.CMQC.MQFMT_STRING

        queue_request = pymqi.Queue(self.qmgr, self.queue_request_name)
        queue_request.put(str_xml_message.encode("UTF-8"), request_md)
        queue_request.close()

        # Set up message descriptor for get.
        response_md = pymqi.MD()
        response_md['CorrelId'] = request_md['MsgId']

        gmo = pymqi.GMO()
        gmo.Options = pymqi.CMQC.MQGMO_WAIT | pymqi.CMQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
        gmo.WaitInterval = 5000  # 5 seconds

        queue_response = pymqi.Queue(self.qmgr, self.queue_response_name)
        message = queue_response.get_no_rfh2(None, response_md, gmo)
        queue_response.close()

        return str(message)


    def close(self):
        self.qmgr.disconnect()
```

I wonder how can I define the MQ Manager's CCSID value and hopefully solve the codepage mismatch.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you create a default message descriptor for the message you send in this line of code:

```
request_md = pymqi.MD()
```

---

By default pymqi (like the underlying IBM MQ C libraries) will set the message descriptor `CodedCharSetId` to the value `CMQC.MQCCSI_Q_MGR`.

This can be seen in the [source](https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/blob/c3a0f19dc991a7b26e34f0e3142ec99e36673519/code/pymqi/__init__.py#L588):

```
['CodedCharSetId', CMQC.MQCCSI_Q_MGR, MQLONG_TYPE],
```

---

The IBM MQ v9.0 KC page [Reference > Developing applications reference > MQI applications reference > Data types used in the MQI > MQMD - Message descriptor > Fields for MQMD > CodedCharSetId (MQLONG)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q097460_.htm) describes how the client handles this:

> For client applications, MQCCSI_Q_MGR is filled in, based on the locale of the client rather than the one on the queue manager.

---

The IBM MQ Troubleshooting document [What CCSID is used by default for WebSphere MQ client messages](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/what-ccsid-used-default-websphere-mq-client-messages) explains this in a slightly different way:

> A MQ client sets the MQCCSI_Q_MGR value based on the environment in which the client application is running.

---

Based on the [850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) CCSID I would guess you are running on a Windows OS that is not in the United States (which commonly uses CCSID 437).

---

You have a few options to override this:

1. You can programmatically override the pymqi MQMD default value like this:

   ```
   request_md.CodedCharSetId = 1208
   ```
2. Set the env variable `MQCCSID` to the value you want (in your case 1208).  This must be set before you connect to mq.  This is documented in the IBM MQ v9.0 KC page [Developing applications > Developing MQI applications with IBM MQ > Writing client procedural applications > Using the MQI in a client application > Choosing client or server CCSID](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q027300_.htm).

   The example below is for Windows:

   ```
   SET MQCCSID=1208
   ```
3. In the `mqclient.ini` you can set the `CCSID=number` under the `CHANNELS` stanza.  This is documented in the IBM MQ v9.0 KC page [Configuring > Configuring connections between the server and client > Configuring a client using a configuration file > CHANNELS stanza of the client configuration file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016860_.htm).  For example:

   ```
   CHANNELS:
      CCSID=1208
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to change the CCSID of the queue manager. Your problem is that your message contains UTF-8 characters, but you have sent it in an envelope describing it as containing CCSID 850 characters. You simply need to update the envelope delivering your message to correctly describe your content.

I am an IBM MQ expert and a 'C' programmer, but not a pymqi programmer, however, looking at the pymqi help and your example, I would expect these are the required additions to your code.

```
# set message descriptor
request_md = pymqi.MD()
request_md.ReplyToQ = self.queue_response_name
request_md.Format = pymqi.CMQC.MQFMT_STRING
request_md.CodedCharSetId = 1208
```

The pymqi help does not include any examples of use of the `CodedCharSetId`, but it would seem that all pymqi fields in the `MQMD` follow the exact same spelling and case as those in the 'C' API header file `cmqc.h`.

Please try this and see if it solves your problem.